# Get two user inputs to sum and display

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables

I thought I would try to get two user inputs to sum and display as a label.  I wrote the code and have been staring and altering the code for two days.  If anyone would kindly help explain what I am doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.  everything is linked correctly in IB and Xcode 5.

I have added the relevant .h and .m files I wrote.  But for some reason no matter what I change I can't get the two user inputs to add together. Thanks for taking the time.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AddViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberOne;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberTwo;

- (IBAction)plusButton:(UIButton *)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *sumTotal;

@end


.m

#import "AddViewController.h"

@interface AddViewController ()

@end

@implementation AddViewController

    int numberOne;
    int numberTwo;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (float) addTwoNumbers:(float) numberOne to: (float)numberTwo
{

    return  ((numberOne) + (numberTwo));
}


- (IBAction)plusButton:(id)sender
{

   // self.sumTotal.text = [self addTwoNumbers: numberOne:numberTwo];

    int numberTwo = ([_numberTwo.text integerValue]);


    int sumTotal = [self addTwoNumbers:(int)numberOne to:(int)numberTwo];

  //  self.sumTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numberOne + numberTwo];

    self.sumTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sumTotal];
}
@end
```

Comment: Like Fade said, make your text labels different than what you have. for example I would call mine num1TxtLabel, num2TxtLabel. Something you can understand right away in your code. You can even rename your ints as numberOneInt, numberTwoInt ... welcome to crazy, nasty and beautiful world of programming

Comment: If you're "relatively new to programming" what the heck are you doing working in Objective-C???

Comment: You never set a value into `numberOne`.

Answer (score 2):

It helps a lot to not name things so similarly since your input fields and int's are confusing you.

You need to add

```
int numberOne = ([_numberOne.text integerValue]);
```

to the plusButton method.  Using floats in the addTwoNumbers: method isn't going to hurt much but you may as well make those int

Comment: Completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your `plusButton:` method:

```
- (IBAction)plusButton:(id)sender {
    int numberOne = [_numberOne.text intValue];
    int numberTwo = [_numberTwo.text intValue];
    int sumTotal = numberOne + numberTwo;
    self.sumTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", sumTotal];
}
```

You also seem to like lots of extra parentheses. No need for most of them.

Also, your `numberOne` and `numberTwo` variables declared just after the `@implementation` line are actually file global variables, not instance variables. Since you don't use them anyway, please get rid of them.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly.  And thanks to everyone for answering.

Comment: Very good. Don't forget to accept the answer (After some appropriate need to wait of course).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
- (IBAction)plusButton:(id)sender{
    int total = [_numberOne.text integerValue] + [_numberTwo.text integerValue];
    self.sumTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", total];
}
```

FYI, this solution uses the values stored in your text views. Really those values should be stored in a "Model" object per MVC conventions.

I suggest at the time a user inputs a number, you use that input to update a model. Then, use the model values to do your calculations. It looks like you tried to do this when you declared...

```
int numberOne;
int numberTwo;
```

...but you're not updating them. I also suggest you rename your views to something like numberOneView so that there is no confusion that you're referencing the int vs. a UITextField.

Comment: Keep in mind that those are not instance variables, they are file global variables since they are not in curly braces as part of the `@implementation` line.

Comment: correct. do they need to be declared static explicitly or will it work as-is?

Comment: Neither. To be ivars they need be like this: `@implementation AddViewController { int numberOne; int numberTwo; }`

Comment: Ah ok, figured static vars would work for what OP is doing (there is only ever 1 instance of AddViewController class), but i agree w/ ivars when that assumption is false.

Comment: Never use statics when you should use ivars, even if you think there will only be one instance of the class at a time. It's just bad design and will likely lead to problems in the future.

Comment: +1 To maddy's comment about static variables. Avoid static/global variables whenever possible. There are only a few limited cases where they are necessary or appropriate, and this is certainly not one of those cases.